# DLL error message connecting to R

Tags: windows, rlink

I am trying to connect to a local version of R from Mathematica 10.1.0 on Windows 10:

```
InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.3.2"]
```

I get the following error message:

> Error: R.DLL version does not match (DLL: 3.3.2; expecting: 3.1.1)

Adding `"RVersion" -> 3.3` doesn't help. I then installed R 3.1.1 locally, and that connected fine using RHomeLocation.

Is 3.3.2 too new? I can't find any documentation indicating what versions of R can be accessed with RLink. A previous answer related to this topic suggested this sort of DLL error was an issue with Mathematica itself.

Unfortunately, I need to use a package that only works with R > 3.2 ([Momocs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Momocs/index.html)). How can I get 3.2 or later working with RLink?

Comment: Please contact Wolfram Support about this and let us know what they said. http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/

Comment: Found what is likely same problem with attempt to load R Version 4.3.0 that runs R as expected on a 64bit Windows 11 platform.  Perhaps a mechanism to load the (upgraded?) .DLL has not kept up with the pace of R upgrades.  I too will be contact WR Support for clarification.  Would seem as if something should have happened on this issue in 6 years.

Comment: I should have added there are no problems running the internal older version of R loaded within RLink.  The line attempting to install R is InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.3.0"]